# Group method only displaying one params

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have:

```
@comparison = Result.group('results.trial_id').having('COUNT(results.variety_id) = 2').where('results.variety_id' => [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]]).
joins(:trial).where('trials.irrigated' => params[:irrigated], 'trials.year' => params[:year]).joins(:regions).where('sites.region_id' => params[:regions])
```

When I inspect @comparison in my view it only shows the results for params[:variety_two] which is variety_id: 2255 and not params[:variety_one]. Why is this?

Output in view

```
[#<Result id: 275428, trial_id: 1038, created_at: "2014-01-29 04:42:43", updated_at: "2014-01-29 04:42:43", variety_id: 2255, year: 2009, lint: 1559.0, turnout: 41>>]
```

So it should also list params[:variety_one] which is variety_id: 2246 as well.

SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT results.year FROM `results` INNER JOIN `trials` ON `trials`.`trial_id` = `results`.`trial_id` INNER JOIN `trials` `trials_results_join` ON `trials_results_join`.`trial_id` = `results`.`trial_id` INNER JOIN `sites` ON `sites`.`site_id` = `trials_results_join`.`site_id` INNER JOIN `regions` ON `regions`.`region_id` = `sites`.`region_id` WHERE `results`.`variety_id` IN (2246, 2255) AND `trials`.`irrigated` IN (2) AND `trials`.`year` IN ('2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013') AND `sites`.`region_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) AND `results`.`year` IN (2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013) GROUP BY results.trial_id HAVING COUNT(results.variety_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: We've been chatting offline about this and this is what I reckon you're after:

You want to get all the ids for the for the trials that match your parameters and have those two varieties, 
and then get all of the results for those trials that have those two varieties?

Something like this (I'm sure this is not the most elegant way and could be tidied up):

```
@trial_ids = Result.where(:variety_id => [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]]).group(:trial_id).having('COUNT(*) = 2').count.keys

@filtered_trials = Trial.where(:trial_id => [@trial_ids]).where('trials.irrigated' => params[:irrigated], 'trials.year' => params[:year]).joins(:regions).where('sites.region_id' => params[:regions])

@all = Result.where(:trial_id => [@filtered_trials.map {|x| x.trial_id}]).where(variety_id: [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]]).select('AVG(lint) AS lint, AVG(turnout) AS turnout')
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks mate!